# Is using a load balancer with ElasticSearch unnecessary?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, lucene, nosql

I have a cluster of 3 ElasticSearch nodes running on AWS EC2.  These nodes are setup using OpsWorks/Chef.  My intent is to design this cluster to be very resilient and elastic (nodes can come in and out when needed).

From everything I've read about ElasticSearch, it seems like no one recommends putting a load balancer in front of the cluster; instead, it seems like the recommendation is to do one of two things:

1. Point your client at the URL/IP of one node, let ES do the load balancing for you and hope that node never goes down.
2. Hard-code the URLs/IPs of ALL your nodes into your client app and have the app handle the failover logic.

My background is mostly in web farms where it's just common sense to create a huge pool of autonomous web servers, throw an ELB in front of them and let the load balancer decide what nodes are alive or dead.  Why does ES not seem to support this same architecture?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't need a load balancer — ES is already providing that functionality. You'd just another component, which could misbehave and which would add an unnecessary network hop.

ES will shard your data (by default into 5 shards), which it will try to evenly distribute among your instances. In your case 2 instances should have 2 shards and 1 just one, but you might want to change the shards to 6 for an equal distribution.

By default replication is set to `"number_of_replicas":1`, so one replica of each shard. Assuming you are using 6 shards, it could look something like this (R is a replicated shard):

- node0: 1, 4, R3, R6
- node1: 2, 6, R1, R5
- node2: 3, 5, R2, R4

Assuming node1 dies, the cluster would change to the following setup:

- node0: 1, 4, 6, R3 + new replicas R5, R2
- node2: 3, 5, 2, R4 + new replicas R1, R6

Depending on your connection setting, you can either connect to one instance (transport client) or you could join the cluster (node client). With the node client you'll avoid double hops, since you'll always connect to the correct shard / index. With the transport client, your requests will be routed to the correct instance.

So there's nothing to load balance for yourself, you'd just add overhead. The auto-clustering is probably ES's greatest strength.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I suppose I'm more concerned about failover balancing.  I understand that ES will do load balancing for me, but what if the node I am connecting to goes down or is taken out of service?  In the case of an ELB (at least as far as web servers go) it would balance requests across all in-service nodes.  Is there a similar pattern for ES clusters?

Comment: @xeraa So the "node" client automatically resolves available elasticsearhc nodes / cluster by doing broadcast or something?

Comment: You can provide an array (or whatever it is called in your programming language) of IPs/DNS names with the right port. At least one of them must be reachable and the rest should be handled by ES

Comment: Do you think if clients are talking over HTTP to cluster, could it be the case that all clients are trying to connect to same node in cluster and the web layer gets exhausted ?

Comment: This might be an issue, but your client library should be able to work around that. For example see "Randomizing Hosts" of the Ruby driver: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-ruby/tree/master/elasticsearch-transport#randomizing-hosts

Comment: The sacrifice in this approach is that now you have a direct dependency in your clients on your server topology. And, no, you aren't "adding another network hop". You're just changing the way the domain name gets resolved. Unless you are talking about even using IP addresses in the client configuration, in which case...yeah.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's a good writeup on how ES balances data internally but a client app connecting to the ES cluster still need a mechanism to switch to node2's IP when node1 fails. A floating IP or an IP load balancer can do that job but it's not included in ES.

Comment: It does answer the question, but it may miss some further information: As mentioned, you can use the node-client-approach to connect your application to the cluster. With this approach, the application will find the correct shards/nodes by itself: You can distribute the search request, when using replica shards - since those will be used for search. By default, the node-client would randomly select an applicable replica or primary per request, distributing the work load.

Answer (score 54):

I believe load balancing an Elasticsearch cluster is a good idea (designing a fault tolerant system, resilient to single node failure.)

To architect your cluster you'll need background on the two primary functions of Elasticsearch: 1. Writing and updating documents and 2. Querying Documents.

**Writing / indexing documents in elasticsearch:**

1. When a new document comes into Elasticsearch to be indexed, Elasticsearch determines the "primary shard" the document should be assigned to using the "Shard Routing Algorithm"
2. The Lucene process associated with the shard "maps" the fields in the document;
3. The Lucene process adds the document to the shard's Lucene "inverted index"
4. Any "replica shard(s)" then receive the document; the replica shard "maps" the document and adds the document to the replica shard's Lucene "inverted index"

**Querying documents in Elasticsearch:**

1. By default, when a query is sent to Elasticsearch, the query hits a node -- this becomes the "query node" or the "gateway query node" for that query
2. The node broadcasts the query to every shard in the index (primary & replica)
3. each shard performs query on the shard's local Lucene inverted index.
4. each shard returns the top 10 - 20 results to the "gateway query node"
5. the "gateway query node" then performs a merge-sort on the combined results returned from the other shards,
6. once the merge-sort is finished, the "gateway query node" and returns results to the client

   - the merge-sort is CPU and Memory resource heavy

**Architect a Load Balancer for Writes / Indexing / Updates**

Elasticsearch self manages the location of shards on nodes.  The "master node" keeps and updates the "shard routing table".  The "master node" provides a copy of the shard routing table to other nodes in the cluster.

Generally, you don't want your master node doing much more than health checks for the cluster and updating routing tables, and managing shards.

It's probably best to point the load balancer for writes to the "data nodes" (Data nodes are nodes that contain data = shards) and let the data nodes use their shard routing tables to get the writes to the correct shards.

**Architecting for Queries**

Elasticsearch has created a special node type: "client node", which contains "no data", and cannot become a "master node".  The client node's function is to perform the final resource heavy merge-sort at the end of the query.

For AWS you'd probably use a c3 or c4 instance type as a "client node"

Best practice is to point the load balancer for queries to client nodes.

Cheers!

**References:**

1. [Elasticsearch Node Types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html)
2. [Elasticsearch: Shard Routing Algorithm](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/routing-value.html)
3. [Elasticsearch: Replica Shards](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/replica-shards.html)
4. [Elasticsearch: Cluster State i.e. the Shard Routing Table](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-state.html)
5. [ElasticHQ - Introduction to Elasticsearch Video](http://www.elastichq.org/blog/)
6. [Elasticsearch: Shard numbers and Cluster Scaling](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/shard-scale.html)

Answer (score 12):

You're quite right to want to design for 'failover', and in AWS, here's how I recommend you do it.

1) Limit the nodes in your cluster that can be elected master. For the rest, set node.client: true. Base your choice of how many master electable nodes you have on how many you want available for failover.

2) Create an ELB that includes only the master electable nodes.

3) In Route 53, create a CNAME for your cluster, with the value set to the DNS name of your ELB.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear what to do when the master node fails. After digging, here are a couple of options:

1. If you re using a client to connect to elasticsearch cluster, you can specify an array of DNS names in the connection configuration. The client will try to resolve DNS in sequence. If the first one fails, the second one will be attempted.
2. Use round-robin DNS. Similar to the option number one, but without the client.
   Both of these options might cause a delay because DNS needs to fail first to be routed to the next available alias. DNS or client have no way of knowing that a particular host is down.
3. Use some sort of load balancer, that way LB will know about misbehaving hosts ahead of time and not cause any delays.

Comment: You have to use single node master configuration.